# Getting the values of a returned JSON object in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I am new to angular and node.js.

Basically, I have a table of items and in each row, there is a button click.
If I click the button which is edit, the details should appear in its corresponding textbox for editing.

```
router.route('/contacts/getone/:pk')
    .get(function(req, res, next){
        pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
            //var id = {pk:req.body.pk};
            var contacts = [];
            console.log("get1");
            console.log(req.params.pk);
            var query = client.query("select * from contacts where pk=($1)", [req.params.pk]);
            query.on('row', function(row) {
                contacts.push(row);
               });
               query.on('end', function() {
                done();
                return res.json(contacts);
            });
        });
    });
```

And this is my angular controller code.

```
$scope.editContact = function(id) {
        contact.getone(id)
        .success(function(data) {

                $scope.contactlist = data;
                //console.log("geone");
                //document.getElementById("fname").value = $scope.contactlist.firstname;
                //console.log("getall");
                //console.log($scope.contactlist.firstname);
                //console.log(data["firstname"]);
                $scope.formData.firstname = $scope.contactlist.firstname;
                $scope.formData.lastname = $scope.contactlist.lastname;
                $scope.formData.address = $scope.contactlist.address;
                $scope.formData.contact = $scope.contactlist.contact;
//                $scope.loading = false;
            });
    };
```

Can anyone tell me how to access the values in data which is returned by my node.js code? The code I have in my angular returns undefined values like `$scope.contactlist.firstname` is undefined.

This is the image of when I do `console.log(data);`

[image: demonstration]

Comment: What `data` is being retrieved in `success` callback ?

Comment: basically the first name, lastname, email and contact. by doing console.log(data); 

the value is this.

$$hashKey: "008"
contact_num: 123
email: "a@gmail.com"
firstname: "boy"
lastname: "kigwa"
pk: 2

Comment: Now, my question is, how do I retrieve the value on the object data in success call back?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to define `formData` as object(`{}`) or else `$scope.formData` will be `undefined` and *you can not set property of undefined*

Data being received from the api is not an `object` but an `array`. You need to return the data once you get the `row`

**Server side**

```js
router.route('/contacts/getone/:pk')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
    pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
      var query = client.query("select * from contacts where pk=($1)", [req.params.pk]);
      query.on('row', function(row) {
        return res.json(row);
      });
    });
  });
```

**Client side**

```js
var data = {
  $$hashKey: "008",
  contact_num: 123,
  email: "a@gmail.com",
  firstname: "boy",
  lastname: "kigwa",
  pk: 2
};
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.contactlist = data;
$scope.formData.firstname = $scope.contactlist.firstname;
$scope.formData.lastname = $scope.contactlist.lastname;
$scope.formData.address = $scope.contactlist.address;
$scope.formData.contact = $scope.contactlist.contact;
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.formData));
```

Comment: it is already define. just didn't include it in the snippet.

.controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', 'contact', function($scope, $http, contact) {
 $scope.formData = {};

Comment: The problem is not the $scope.formData.firstname but the $scope.contactlist.firstname which is undefined. Kindly see the picture below on how the data looks like when I do console.log(data); Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Rayin Dabre
----This is my the code of my controller.

```html
angular.module('ContactsControl', [])

.controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', 'contact', function($scope, $http, contact) {
 $scope.formData = {};
 
 contact.get()

   .success(function(data) {
    console.log("getall");
    $scope.contactlist = data;
//    $scope.loading = false;
   });
 $scope.editContact = function(id) {
  contact.getone(id)
  .success(function(data) {

    $scope.contactlist = data;
    //console.log("geone");
    //document.getElementById("fname").value = $scope.contactlist.firstname;
    console.log(data);
    //console.log($scope.contactlist.firstname);
    //console.log(data["firstname"]);
    $scope.formData.firstname = $scope.contactlist.firstname;
    $scope.formData.lastname = $scope.contactlist.lastname;
    $scope.formData.address = $scope.contactlist.address;
    $scope.formData.contact = $scope.contactlist.contact;
//    $scope.loading = false;
   });
 };
```